# Double precision problems when zooming in

Tags: c#, double-precision

I have this algorithm that calcuates the mandelbrot value of a point (x0,y0) (x0 and y0 are somewhere between -1 and 1 i thought, not very important). This is all going very well when `scale` isn't getting too big, but at higher values of `scale`, the values returned are very inaccurate and my graphic output starts to go freaky. How do i predict from what value of `scale` this occurs?

```
    public static byte CalculateMandelbrot(double x0, double y0,double scale)
    {
        x0 /= scale;
        y0 /= scale;
        double y = 0;
        double x = 0;
        byte i = 0;
        while (x * x + y * y < 4)
        {
            double tx = x;
            x = x * x - y * y + x0;
            y = 2 * tx * y + y0;
            i++;
            if (i == 0xFF) break;
        }

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the maths, but since you only give it 0xFF iterations, maybe it isn't enough to converge.

Comment: @jake No the low amount of iterations just causes some shapes to be rounded a bit, also unwanted, but an entirely different problem.

Comment: You have 6 multiplications instead of 3. Decimal still is painfully slow, but you can almost double its speed by refactoring your code..:`            do
            {
                x2 = x * x;
                y2 = y * y;
                y = x * y;
                y += y + y0;
                x = x2 - y2;
                x +=  x0;
                k++;
            }
            while (k < kMax && (x2 + y2) < limit);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A double has 53 bits of precision. This amounts to about 16 decimal places.

If you zoom in on your fractal 10^13 times, and make picture of 1000x1000 pixels, the precision is about the same as the screen resolution: the minimal change possible in a double is a step of one pixel on the screen.

But you will get into trouble before that, because you iterate the mandelbrot formula a hundred times iteratively on the same number. Each calculation adds a roundoff error (multiple ones, probably) of about 1/10^16. It is possible (although tedious) to predict when this gets noticable.

The FPU internally has a higher number of bits than standard double, this will reduce the abovementioned effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic "decimal vs double" pitfall.
Try using 'decimal' for all vars and see if it clicks.

From the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page:

> Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has a greater
>   precision and a smaller range

There are also arbitrary precision implementations like [BigFloat Class](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Mathematics.BigFloat.aspx).

Comment: I tried that before. With doubles it runs at about 6 fps in a small window, but with decimal it didn't even make it into 1 frame after 1 minute.

Comment: Nah, the difference is about 20-30x.